# How to add calculated values in a timebased dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

Lets assume there is a dataframe with readings like this:

```
   id  meter  reading       date
0   2      2     8232 2023-09-01
1   5      2     8267 2023-11-01
2   8      2     8472 2023-12-01
3  11      2     9354 2024-02-17
4  14      2     9417 2024-03-04
```

The consumption for the last year would be like this: reduce the dataframe to the last year. Calculate the difference between the last and the first value (equals 240) . The calculation for the current year is pretty much the same (equals 63).

Problem: the actual consumption is 1185, which is a way more than 240+63.

The challenge is that the timeframe between the last reading from the previous year and the first reading of the current year is to long. The better approach would be to calculate the assumed value for the turn of the year with steps like this:

- identify the timeframe with an turn of the year included
- calculate the timeframe  (31+31+17=79)
- calculate the consumption in this timeframe (882)
- calculate the daily consumption during this timeframe (882/79=11)
- add an entry for 2023-12-31 with value (30*11+8472=8802)
- add an entry for 2024-01-01 with value (9354-47*11=8826)

and calculate the consumptions of this (591) and last year (570), which is in total (1161) a way closer to the actual number (1185).

Does someone know how to achieve this with pandas dataframe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Code**

at first make to datetime & find YS  & Y

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
date1 = pd.date_range(df['date'].min(), df['date'].max(), freq='Y').tolist()
date2 = pd.date_range(df['date'].min(), df['date'].max(), freq='YS').tolist()
```

interpolate

```
out = (df.set_index('date')
       .reindex(df['date'].tolist() + date1 + date2)
       .sort_index()
       .assign(reading=lambda x: x['reading'].interpolate(method='time'))
       .reset_index()[df.columns]
)
```

out:

```
    id  meter       reading date
0   2.00    2.00    8232.00 2023-09-01
1   5.00    2.00    8267.00 2023-11-01
2   8.00    2.00    8472.00 2023-12-01
3   NaN     NaN     8811.23 2023-12-31
4   NaN     NaN     8822.54 2024-01-01
5   11.00   2.00    9354.00 2024-02-17
6   14.00   2.00    9417.00 2024-03-04
```

Comment: Wow, impressive short and effective! Thank you! With the new knowledge, I even changed it a bit:

    yearEnd = pd.date_range(df['date'].min(), df['date'].max(), freq='YE').tolist()
    allMonthStarts = pd.date_range(df['date'].min(), df['date'].max(), freq='MS').tolist() #includes 01/01

    df = df.set_index('date').reindex(df['date'].tolist() + yearEnd + allMonthStarts).sort_index().assign(reading=lambda x: x['reading'].interpolate(method='time')).reset_index()[df.c>
    df.drop_duplicates(subset=['date'], keep='first', inplace=True)

This interplolate even more values.